# How can we select data when we used key words as access database table names and field name in delphi

Tags: delphi, ms-access, delphi-xe, ms-access-2000

I am using delphi and access database. I used a keyword as a table name and field name. 
Ex : User \ Date \ Password.
How can i access it from delphi?
Below is the code i tried. It is working when i run it in Access. but same query can not run from delphi. it says syntax error in query.

```
select * from "User"
select * from User
```

Comment: You mean that the table name is a reserved word ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
select * from [user]
```

Maybe this link is something for you to read :
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-SQL-basic-concepts-vocabulary-and-syntax-444d0303-cde1-424e-9a74-e8dc3e460671